# How can I refresh the data without breaking the canvas

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, canvas

I have a basic weather application that gets data from forecast.io and displays icons using the related [skycons](https://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/) which draw and animates icons using the html5 canvas

Everything seems to works fine, but i have to update the weather regularly without refresh the whole page and the jquery Ajax load method seemed like an answer to my problem. The text data refresh fine and gets the new information but the canvas seems to break.

I managed to isolate the problem. It seems I don't understand how the html canvas works.
Here is a simpler problem

This code draws a red rectangle and refreshes part of the page with the jquery load method

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="weather">
        <canvas id="icon"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    var i = document.getElementById('icon');
    var c = i.getContext('2d');
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
</script>

<script>
    var container = $("#container");
    setInterval(function () {
        container.load("index.php #weather");
        console.log("refresh")

    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Unfortunately, the red rectangle disappear on the reload. [gif](http://recordit.co/mGLjJ2ETqw)
My question is, what should I do to make it stay/reappear?
I tried putting the canvas code inside the interval function after the load, but the rectangle appears for a fraction of a second to only vanish again?
Please try this on your own machines to confirm my problems
Can someone explain me how the canvas works and please guide me to a solution

The problem is the same for my icons they blink for a second after the reload to disappear
recordit.co/Ta6u5oVkie

Comment: You need to redraw the canvas after you get the data from index.php the container will not refresh until the data has loaded which will be after the timeout function has run. I dont know jQuery but surely there is a onload event for the container.load you create.

Comment: You `url` is not valid an will make `load()` to fail (and thus empty your container). But anyway, what is the content  of `index.php` ? Does it contains javascript code too ? Why do you use `load()` (which will write HTML) instead of an simple `get()` to only receive the new data and then update your already there canvas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem. It was a common beginner's mistake, I didn't redraw in the canvas in the callback of the ajax function.

thanks